# Is it possible to change the value of an element using Stylish extension?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, stylish

```
<input type="text" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Search box. Find messages, documents, photos or people" class="select-input react-typeahead-input k_w W_6D6F P_Z1E2YFn i_6LEV M_0 b_0 A_6EWk y_ZwubDW I_T p_R Z_N ui-autocomplete-input" value="" placeholder="Find messages, documents, photos or people" tabindex="10" maxlength="2000" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="on" autocorrect="off" data-rapid_p="2">
```

I want to change **placeholder="Find messages, documents, photos or people"** to **placeholder="Search..."** How to accomplish this using Stylish extension for Google Chrome? If it's not possible in Stylish, which JavaScript extension can I use for Google Chrome since Stylish doesn't support JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware it is not possible to do this with CSS, and therefore Stylish. However, [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) is a Chrome extension that allows for Javascript userscripts to be injected into pages on load.